# Breaking down composite arithmetic expressions in a Java string

Tags: java

Given a string like

```
A + B * C / (D + E)
```

The algorithm will break the string down into a list of binary operations:

- Add D and E (result #1)
- Multiply B and C (result #2)
- Divide result #1 by result #2 (result #3)
- Add result #3 to A

Basically, the order in which a programming language like Java would execute the expression.

What is the best approach for this sort of problem?

Comment: You'll need to define a [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) and then write a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) for it.  Alternatively, use [some existing library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jeval/).

Comment: convert to [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) using [Dijkstra Two Stack Algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)... alternatively just use the Java Evaluate function...

Comment: One of the examples for [jparsec](https://github.com/abailly/jparsec) is [pretty much this problem exactly](https://github.com/abailly/jparsec/blob/master/jparsec-examples/src/main/java/org/codehaus/jparsec/examples/calculator/Calculator.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Best" approach is in the eye of the beholder. A reasonably common and easy to implement approach would be to build a simple [*recursive descent parser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) by following these steps:

- Write a method that "tokenizes" your expression (i.e. converts it to a collection of operators, operands, and parentheses, e.g. `"A"`, `"+"`, `"B"`, `"*"`, `"C"`, `"/"`, `"("`, `"D"`, `"+"`, `"E"`, `")"`
- Define a method for processing a top-level expression as a sequence of zero or more additions or subtractions
- Define a method for processing an addition or a subtraction as a sequence of zero or more multiplications or divisions
- Define a method for processing a multiplication or a division as a sequence of zero or more *primary expressions*
- Define a method for processing a primary expression as a variable or a top-level expression enclosed in parentheses

The last point is key to understanding the recursive descent parsing: whenever you encounter an opening parentheses, you call back the method for processing a top-level expression, and then verify that the next token after processing is the closing parenthesis.